# Display selected image in a JTextPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextpane

How can I show an image I have selected from the file chooser in a my textpane (jTextPaneBody)? This is the code I have so far but I don't know what else needs to be added in order to achieve this.

```
private void jButtonAttachActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
        jc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
        jc.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = jc.getSelectedFile();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Then you can use [`JTextPane#insertIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) or [`JTextPane#insertComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertComponent(java.awt.Component)) to physically add the image based on your needs